# C# - Parsing response content results from Zoho Creator Rest API

Tags: c#, rest, api, zoho

Having trouble parsing the Zoho Creator Rest API returns. Sample return results:

> {{"formname":["RestAPI",{"operation":["add",{"values":{"Name":"Gary","Basic":"10000","Hobbies":["Reading","Writing"],"DOB":"12-Jun-1980","Address":"USA","ID":89597000010897007},"status":"Success"}]}]}

Using the code below to return a JObject in order to pull properties:

```
/* send post request here */
HttpContent _content = null;
var response = this.client.PostAsync(this.PostUrl,_content).Result;  

/* parse request response here - need to record all data from return response */
string responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
JObject result = JObject.Parse(responseString);
```

For some reason I am not able to access any properties of the "result" object. I have tried using indexed and JToken approaches and none are returning me the values.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend trying JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(import the newtonsoft.json package) and using that on your responseString. You're going to need to create a c# class that matches the structure of the JSON you're receiving to make the DeserializeObject method work though. If you want to just use .(whatever property) to get the information from the response though, I recommend trying Json.Decode(responseString);

Comment: Was hoping to avoid creating class objects, but it is the only thing left I haven't tried. What namespace are you using for Json.Decode?

Comment: @broseidon https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.helpers.json.decode?view=aspnet-webpages-3.2

Answer (score 0):

Ugly but it works - unfortunately it only works for the specific return, there's probably a dynamic solution using similar methods:

```
/* parse request response here - need to record all data from return response */
string responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
JObject result = JObject.Parse(responseString);
var _formname = result["formname"] as JArray;
var step1 = _formname[1];
string operation = step1["operation"][0].ToString();
var values = step1["operation"][1]["values"];
var status = step1["operation"][1]["status"].ToString();
```